# Empty/broken zip file getting downloaded using ZipArchive

Tags: php, php-ziparchive

I'm using ZipArchive to zip and download the dynamically generated pdf files. The files are getting generated in the designated folder but when I'm trying to download the zip file, the 1KB broken file is getting download.

I've tried this code at my local wampp and here it works perfectly and the proper zip file is getting generated but in production the broken zip is getting downloaded. I believe there's some server variable which might be resulting this?

```
// creating directory in the server with timestamp
$dirName = strtotime(date('Y-m-d H:i:s'));
$dirPath = "/var/www/...../foldertobezipped/" . $dirName;
mkdir($dirPath);

// generating and storing the generated pdf files in the $dirPath folder
foreach ($resultArray as $filelist) {
    $this->invoicepdfview($orderid);
}

// zip file name
$archive = $dirName . '.zip';

// invoking ZipArchive
$zip = new ZipArchive;
$zipPath = $dirPath . "/" . $archive;
$zip->open($zipPath, ZipArchive::CREATE);

// scanning all the files to be zipped
$files = scandir($dirPath);

// removing the unwanted key-value from the array
unset($files[0], $files[1]);

// adding files to the zip file
foreach ($files as $file) {
    $new_filename = substr($dirPath . '/' . $file, strrpos($dirPath . '/' . $file, '/') + 1);
    $zip->addFile($dirPath . '/' . $file, $new_filename);
}
$zip->close();

// downloading the zipped file
header('Content-Type: application/zip');
header('Content-disposition: attachment; filename=' . $zipPath);
header('Content-Length: ' . filesize($zipPath));
readfile($zipPath);
unlink($zipPath);
```

I've checked and compared most of the php.ini variables which could affect this between local WAMPP and production server. Could someone help me out of this? Where am I missing something?

P.S. - I've provided 777 permission to the directory where the files are being created.

Comment: What does the generated files look like? Are they correct?

Comment: @MagnusEriksson: Yes, the files are correct. Only thing I is believe is that while creating ZIP the files are not getting added to the downloadable file.

Comment: @MagnusEriksson: Is there some way that I can debug this PHPArchive ? Pardon me if this is very naive. I've used PHP error reporting, but nothing substantial came up.

Comment: What if you remove `unlink($archive)`, do you see the zip-file on the server? If no, then it wasn't properly created. If yes, download it from the server (using FTP or something) and see it that one works.

Comment: Also, check the servers error log to see if you get any warnings or errors, Make sure that error reporting is set to E_ALL so we can see all the errors while debugging.

Comment: Plus, open the downloaded, defect zip file in a text editor, and check if any PHP error messages might have found their way in there.

Comment: @MagnusEriksson I tried that as well ,but to no avail. Where would the zip file be created?

Comment: @misorude Thanks for that input, I just checked and here's the errors logged Message:  ZipArchive::close(): Failure to create temporary file: Permission denied
Message:  filesize(): stat failed for 1562246748.zip
Message:  readfile(1562246748.zip): failed to open stream: No such file or directory

Comment: Please check what `sys_temp_dir` is set to, and if your PHP has write permission there. (`var_dump(ini_get('sys_temp_dir'));`, or by calling `phpinfo()`.)

Comment: Set `$dirName` to contain an absolute path to some folder you can write to. You can use the system temp dir or your own, it doesn't matter as long as PHP can write in that folder.

Comment: @MagnusEriksson I've already provided absolute path for the files being zipped in the code.

Comment: @misorude I've just checked the info file and 'sys_temp_dir' says 'No value'

Comment: Then it should fall back to the “default” temp directory the OS specifies, but usually PHP should be allowed to write there … If you have access to the server resp. PHP configuration, you could try if explicitly specifying a different temp dir you know your PHP can write to changes things - but this can only be done in the php.ini or httpd.conf, not a run-time. (The error message suggest it was a problem with the temp dir, but to make sure I’d try to specify the filename the zip should be created under using a full, absolute path as well.)

Comment: @misorude One small clarification I require..Where's the zip file being created before getting downloaded? Is it the defined application's tmp folder or server tmp or somewhere else ? How can I change that path to my application's defined tmp folder path?

Comment: The file itself is created in the location you specified in `$archive`.

Comment: @misorude $archive only holds the file name of the zip file to be created. I've even checked it in my local setup where it's functioning properly, the Zip file is not getting created neither in the application tmp nor in the folder from where the pdf files are being zipped.

Comment: _“$archive only holds the file name of the zip file to be created”_ - if you don’t specify a path, the current working directory of the script will be used automatically. This part does not have anything to do with any temp directories, the file gets written to the place _you_ specified. Use `realpath($archive);` after the file was created, that should show you the full absolute path.

Comment: @misorude if a zip file is created, i should be able to view it in file directory listing using FTP client. I don't find the zip file created at any possible locations I'm looking for. Is there a way I can force the zip file to be created forcibly to custom location within my application root folder.

Comment: Sure, specify the full absolute path from the server file system root directory, instead of just a filename.

Comment: @misorude This creates a new challenge that the zip file now being downloaded is named as the whole absolute path with "/" replaced with "-". I've updated the new code in the initial question.

Comment: Hm, that’s really weird behavior. The manual for the `open` method mentions nothing of the sort; the parameter is called `filename`, but that doesn’t usually mean it must be a file name _only_. Anyway, then keep it with just the file name. The working directory of the script should be the one it is in, if it is a stand-alone script; if it gets included somewhere, then you can use `getcwd` to find out.

Comment: Thanks @misorude you have been a great support. Fixing double quote in header resolved all issues and the zip file got downloaded neatly with appropriate file-name.

For future seekers for the solution: 
   Please mind the single and double quote usage for file download.

header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=\"" . basename($name) . "\";");